# "What surprised him the most "is/was" how they emptied the box" - what is the difference in meaning?

Tags: meaning, tense

**Example 1**

> "What surprised him the most **is** how they emptied the box"

**Example 2**

> "What surprised him the most **was** how they emptied the box"

What is the difference in meaning?

For me, the first sentence suggests that the speaker is describing something that continues to surprise him in the present or that the surprise is an ongoing feeling.

Comment: It's the same as in French.

Comment: Don't overthink it. ***By default*** we'd normally echo Past Tense ***surprised*** with ***was***. The speaker *might* say ***is*** to reflect the fact that ***he himself*** still finds the situation surprising, even though he's actually talking about how ***someone else*** was surprised in the past. But he might just use ***is*** for no particular reason. Other native speakers listening to him probably wouldn't even notice if speaker used the less common tense - but even if they *did* notice, they probably wouldn't assume the choice of tense somehow affected the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the present tense form "is" suggests an action in the present time. However, it is unclear how a past action ("surprised") would be performing an "action" in the present time ("is").<sup>1</sup> Therefore, there seems to be an incongruity, and many people would consider sentence 1 to be incorrect. That being said, it wouldn't be very uncommon to hear a native speaker say sentence 1, especially in casual speech.

However, there's another reason to avoid mixing tenses. This is an example of what is often called a "pseudo-cleft" sentence, and it's common in such constructions to keep the tenses consistent. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence#Wh-cleft/Pseudo-cleft) gives the following example:

> What Mary **bought** **was** a first edition.

Unlike with sentence 1, I don't think that anyone could find fault with the verb tenses in sentence 2. I'd recommend using that version instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> In other contexts this could make sense. For example: "When the criminal **committed** the crime **is** the subject of my investigation." The first action occurred in the past while the second occurs in the present.

Comment: You could be surprised in the past by a fact that continues to be true. And although "surprise" normally refers to a sudden moment, it can mean something continues to puzzle or confuse ("I'm constantly surprised by..." is not incorrect). When both are true you might use "is" - although it's certainly not required: "What surprised him the most is that the capital of Australia is boring provincial Canberra." But that's quite unusual.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, I don't think that I'd call your Canberra example incorrect, but I agree that it's unusual.